# Looking for a End-to-End tutorial to develop a NodeJs Blockchain Appliation using Hyperledger Fabric and Composer REST SERVER

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

Since more than one month, I am working on creating a multi Organization Hyperledger Fabric Application.

I started with Composer, used playground to test my business logic. Then deployed it to the Locally running Fabric Network and used the COMPOSER REST Server to interact with the Blockchain.

The problem started when I wanted to use my Node Application with this network. I can't get my head around participants, network cards, importing these cards, binding these cards, having a wallet for these cards, Activating these cards, enrolling them and doing all this from the NODE Application.

I want One tutorial which will help me connecting a NODE application to a Blockchain network with a Business card and explain everything in layman terms.

Bottom Line: **I want to develop a node application, which will use the REST server-generated for the locally running Hyperledger Fabric using Composer.** Any suggestion on End-to-End tutorials or step by step method to understand these concepts will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need can be found here:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html

it covers everything you need to create a fully fledged application using the node SDK. Make sure you follow all the resources including the Setting up your first network tutorial. The link is on that page.

The problem with composer is that it is not developed anymore by IBM:

https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/composer/message/125

as such I would not recommend you spend any more time on it.

Comment: First of all, Thank you for taking the time and answering the question. But I would like to know if there is a similar detailed end-to-end tutorial which involves Hyperledger Composer and composer rest server?

Comment: I tried the Tutorial and I tried to use it on my application. Now I am having issues with subscribing to chaincode events. Can You please help me with that, More details over here on this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55062756/hyperledger-fabric-1-4-how-to-test-and-verify-registerchaincodeevent-function